# Rails 3 - callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

`User` is a nested attribute of `Announcement`. When a new `announcement` is created, it will create a new `user` if its email is not found. Otherwise it should just post `announcement` into the existing `user`'s record.

I am not sure which callback to use `before_create` or `before_save`. The following code still does not allow new `announcement` to be posted into the existing `user` record. A complete newbie, please help.

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :content, :users_attributes 

  has_many :users, :through => :awards

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:email].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  before_save :find_user

  private
  def find_user(user)
     If User.find(params[:email]).nil?
       @user = User.new
       @user.save
     else
     @user = User.find(params[:email])
  end
end
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting for blocks of code (indent 4 spaces on each line that is code, or just highlight it all and hit the "{}" button on the editor toolbar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use any callbacks at all.  Rails handles creating and deleting of nested attributes automatically which makes the accepts_nested_attributes_for macro so great.  You should not have to manually save, create, or delete except in your controller when you call new and update_attributes.  You may be having problems because your awards association should be defined before your users association.  In your code sample I don't see any definition for an awards association even though your users association is through awards.  Otherwise I would check your controller and view code.  A common problem I have is passing the wrong parameters from the view (make sure you use the fields_for helper in the view).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: MDaubs, thanks for your help.  You are right that nested attributes will automatically save - that's the error that i need to solve.  For an example, if the user already existed, the current code will show "this user's email already existed".  How can i do this: do not create new user if this user email is already in the system, otherwise go ahead to create a new user account.  The award model is just a through model.  I hope that this clarifies things a bit.  Thanks.

Comment: @coder If you pass the user ID along in the view then Rails will recognize that the User already exists and not try to create a new one.  Using select boxes or a list for e-mail addresses would make this trivial but I'm guessing you are using text boxes?  Two options I can think of, maybe someone else has something better.  1) Sprinkle some AJAX over the problem... when the user types in an e-mail make an asynchronous call to load the user ID for that e-mail address into a hidden field.  2) Don't use nested attributes, do it manually.  If it were me I'd go for #1.

Comment: @coder This might prove useful, too... let the tokenize gem do the heavy lifting for you: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Comment: Thanks.  I have been researching all over the web last week and am still struggling.  Will take a look at this railscast.  Have a nice week ahead!